# Start new line with serial communication

Tags: serial-port, arduino, putty

I am trying to get an arduino to tell my computer what the state of it's relays is.  And for some reason every time it sends a new string PuTTY leaves the horizontal position of the last text.  This makes for a very ugly display.

I would like PuTTY to look like the arduino serial manager.

Here is what it looks like from the arduino serial manager
[image]

This is what it looks like in PuTTY
[image]

This is the code I am using to send to computer from arduino. 
[image]

Comment: btw that `comp` thingy is extremely inefficient, use a bit mask instead.

Comment: Well, this is my first time doing anything with a serial connection.  And it is something I found online.  I would actually prefer to send a hex number over insead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you should use "\r\n" instead of "\n" at the end of lines.

Comment: More detailed: "\n" is character with code 0x0A called "new line", while "\r" is 0x0D - "carriage return". Different terminals understand these characters in different ways: there is DOS-like way, when "\n" just places carriage down one line, not changing horisontal position. And there is UNIX-like way, when "\n" moves carriage at the beginning of new line.

Answer (score 9):

You could have set `Implicit CR in every LF` option from PuTTY's terminal options instead of changing every line termination in your code from `\n` to `\r\n`.

Answer (score 2):

Send `\r\n` instead of `\n` only as end-of-line marker. A lot of terminals (incl. Putty, Minicom) require it.